# Setting a fixed stop loss

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I wanted to have a fixed sl at the lowest point of last 10 candlea using ta.lowest function. But every time I tried, it keeps updating the stop loss on every new candle bar. How can I solve this issue?

```
// @version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

import PineCoders/VisibleChart/4

bullish = close[1] > open[2] and high > low[2]    
fvg_value = input.float(0.0001)    
buf = (low - high[2])>fvg_value    
buy  = bullish and buf    
bsl = ta.valuewhen(buy,ta.lowest(low,10),0)

if (bullish and buf)    
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)    
strategy.exit("Take Profit/ Stop Loss","Long", stop = bsl)
```